# get Dataset from web service

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, visual-studio-2008

Here's the case:
I developed a web service which simply gets string arguments and returns `DataSet`:

```
[WebMethod]
        public DataSet login(string strClientCertificate, string strClientChallengeSigned, string MsgChallenge, string rndNum)
```

I want to consume this web service in client side so I prepared arguments and sent it to my referenced web service:

in client side:

```
DataSet xmlResponse = new DataSet();

MySrvRef.StockServiceSoapClient proxy2 = new StockServiceClient.MySrvRef.StockServiceSoapClient();

xmlResponse = proxy2.login(strCert, strSignedMsg, message, randomNum);
```

All I want is showing xmlResponse to client, but I've got this error in VS2008:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException'
>   occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: The remote server returned an unexpected
>   response: (400) Bad Request.

I am totally confused. Any ideas?

**[EDIT1]**

I've already changed the content length in `app.config` file in client side:

```
<basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="StockServiceSoap" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00"
                    receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false"
                    bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                    maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
                    messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
                    useDefaultWebProxy="true">
                    <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647"
                        maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                    <security mode="None">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
                            realm="" />
                        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
                    </security>
                </binding>
            </basicHttpBinding>
```

**[EDIT 2]**
I even changed my method to simple string return method:

```
[WebMehod]
   public string login(string x, string y, string z, string w)
   {
       return "yes";
   }
```

call it from client side but got the same protocol exception :( .

I have another method in my service which is defined as:

```
   [WebMehod]
       public byte[] getChallenge()
```

and I call it without any problem in client side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. When I insert a break point in my web service method (with arguments), it was not getting hit. So I investigate around the problem and found out that one of my string arguments was not recognized as a `string` argument in `C#` and that's the reason that my web service method was not called from client side and I got the **protocol exception error**. Hope this will help others who will have the same issue.